# При синхронизации с сайтом не выгружаются цены и остатки по складам, нет файла offers.xml - 1С

Tags: wordpress, 1с, синхронизация

Все товары на сайт выгружаются, кроме наличия и цен. Нет файла offers.xml
Когда я в разделе "Узел обмена с сайтом" выбираю "Цены по соглашениям и остатки товаров на складах" то при выгрузке происходит ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда экспортирую все данные для теста в XML-файл, то есть такое поле: МеждународноеСокращение="-" 
Может в этом проблема.

При экспорте, в XML-файл, не происходит выгруз цен и остатка на складке, так как синхронизация успешно проходит только без галки "Цены по соглашениям и остатки товаров на складах"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, в какой-то из единиц измерения (из одноименного справочника) в поле "Международное сокращение" поставлен дефис ("-"; а по правилам должна быть трёхбуквенная аббревиатура), и эта единица измерения используется в качестве единицы измерения остатков какой-то позиции номенклатуры. Найдите эту единицу измерения и очистите в ней поле "Международное сокращение".

Comment: Как перейти в одноименный справочник? По номенклатуре полазил, не нашел такого поля

Comment: Конфигурация какая?

Comment: Попробуйте через меню "Все функции...", справочник "Единицы измерения", в большинстве типовых он должен быть.

Comment: конфигурация : http://prntscr.com/ersvco

Comment: Вообщем проблема решена!)
В разделе "нормативно-справочная информация" - "Единицы измерения" в пункте "Международное соглашение" было прописано "-". Так как по условия длинна строки должна быть 3 символа, то заменил значение равное 3 символам.
После этого, обмен успешно завершился